# How to pass arguments to custom validator?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I want to pass an array of prefix strings to my custom validator to check that the value being validated starts with one of the prefixes. Here is my validator:

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'prefixValidator' })
class PrefixValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface 
{
  validate(value: string, validationArguments?: ValidationArguments): boolean 
  {
    for (const prefix of prefixes) //HOW DO I PASS prefixes IN?
      if (value.startsWith(prefix)) 
        return true;

    return false;
  }
}

class DTO 
{
  @Validate(PrefixValidator) //Would like to pass in array of prefix strings here
  myString: string
}
```

How do do I pass in an array of prefix strings to my validator and access them within the validator?

Comment: you could have a function that returns a new class that will have the prefixes list on it, like this: https://wanago.io/2021/12/13/api-nestjs-mixin-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being late here, I answer in case someone will need. You can check the last example in this section https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-classes to see how they get `CustomTextLength`.

Back to your problem, `PrefixValidator` you passed in validate decorator will be in `validationArguments.constraints`

```js
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'prefixValidator' })
class PrefixValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface 
{
  validate(value: string, validationArguments?: ValidationArguments): boolean 
  {
    const [prefixes] = validationArguments.constraints; // destructuring it here
    for (const prefix of prefixes)
      if (value.startsWith(prefix)) 
        return true;

    return false;
  }
}

class DTO 
{
  @Validate(PrefixValidator, yourPrefixes)
  myString: string
}
```